# Why is http://www loading quicker than http:// alone?

Tags: http, url

According to pingdom tests (though I don't know entirely how accurate they are) my website takes significantly longer to load when I search for it via http://www.mediainfocus.co.uk rather than http://mediainfocus.co.uk without the www.

It appears to do some kind of redirect before loading. It's painfully slow for visitors, but I cannot work out what is causing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: same times for me. Have you considered that the server does not have a lot of bandwidth?

Comment: My times from California:
mediainfocus.co.uk -- average 9ms, max 28ms, average 14ms
www.mediainfocus.co.uk -- average 9ms, max 16ms, average 11ms

Could have just been a blip?

These were ping times. Pasting into a browser several times gave complete loads within 1 second of each other. Loads were not super speedy, but not super slow -- about what I'd expect for a graphics-heavy site.

Comment: After accounting for caching (loading both urls twice), the load time is exactly the same in my browser.  The www was quite slow on the first load.  Perhaps the www is loading some static ssn content the non-www is not?

Comment: Thanks a lot ladies and gents. Ive now put a CDN in place to try and take some of the load, and a Wordpress Cache plugin. I'll keep an eye on it to see if this decreases my load times.

Answer (score 0):

`www.mediainfocus.co.uk` and `mediainfocus.co.uk` are two separate subdomains, as far as a web browser is concerned.

If they happen to resolve via DNS to two different IPs, then maybe `www.mediainfocus.co.uk` is running on a slower server than `mediainfocus.co.uk` is running on.

The more likely scenario is that HTTP requests sent to `www.mediainfocus.co.uk` are simply replying back with HTTP redirects to `mediainfocus.co.uk`.  It is not unusual to have a subdomain redirect to another subdomain.  But that would be better handled by using DNS aliases instead of HTTP redirects.  If you have a lot of embedded resources on your pages (images, multimedia, etc), clients could be wasting a lot of bandwidth roundtripping back and forth for every `www.mediainfocus.co.uk` URL being redirected to a corresponding `mediainfocus.co.uk` URL.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Labeau, is this something I can resolve from my Domain/hosting control panel?